# Photoshop: prevent path from escaping image bounds

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, bounding-box

In Adobe Photoshop, I have many existing images each with several saved paths. With many of the paths, an anchor point extends outside the bounds of the image, as seen below (path shaded in 3px blue, image is a black rectangle on a white background).

[image: Image with path outside image bounds]

Is there a function to automatically clip the path and add an anchor point where the path crosses `x = {0, max_x}` and `y = {0, max_y}` and remove the points outside the image, as manually performed below?

[image: Image with path inside image bounds]

Comment: I don't believe anything like this exists.

Comment: if that's a scripting question: also note that you can't modify Photoshop paths, you'll have create new ones with modified coordinates